# Serilog log output with custom formatting

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am attempting to create a custom template for logging JSON format and writing it to a file using the following tech stack in my environment:

1. DotNet 6 - WebAPI
2. Serilog

My expectation for the log file is to have the following format:

`{"level":"info","message":"order confirmation email sent to \"jack@example.com\"","service":"checkoutservice","span_id":"197492ff2b4e1c65","timestamp":"2022-10-10T22:17:14.841359661Z","trace_id":"e12c408e028299900d48a9dd29b0dc4c"}`

Please advise me on how to define the template in my appsettings.json file.